# Installing Android API 16 causing Problems

Tags: android

I am a very new Android Developer.

I am using API 17 and I want to test an app  with API 16, 
I changed the `project.properties` `target=android-17` to `target=android-16`
Then it appears to have this error:

```
Unable to resolve target 'android-16'
```

What I did was to go to Android SDK Manager to download and install API 16, 
after that, nothing works, 
everything on MainActivity are errors, 
I cannot run any projects nor creating any new project.

Could somebody tell me how to fix it? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try editing the project using right-click on the project name, instead of changing 1 file.

Comment: Check Window-> preferences -> android should have 4.1.2. as per updations.

Comment: Hi Sarang, I can't see preferences in Window, I'm uisng Eclipse...

Comment: Hi RvdK, what exactly should I change by right-click?

Comment: did you checked your manifest file ? with target api ? and also right click on you prject -> go to properties -> then click android -> set your target api as latest updated version.

Comment: Are you sure you have downloaded API level 16 SDK?

Wclipse Window menu >>  Android SDK manager. check there API 16 are installed or not?

If they are installed. then go to Eclipse Help >> check for updates.

Comment: hi  itsrajesh4uguys, here I found the problem, when I go into Properties -> Android -> Target API is empty!!! I cannot set any Target API here

Comment: Hi Umer Abid, yes the SDK Manager shows that API 16 is installed